# Unable to connect IBOutlet to XIB File

Tags: swift, xib, nib, iboutlet

I am trying to implement Koloda card swiping style.  I have created a .xib file structured as Image 1 & 2.[image: xib file structure]

As you can see in Image 1, I have set the File's Owner as the XIB Files custom class.

In image 2, I have left the class blank (not sure if this is correct)

My NIB class is per the below code.

```
import UIKit
import Koloda

class CardView: KolodaView {

var view: UIView!
var nibName: String = "CardView"
var uid: String!

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setUp()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUp()
}

func setUp() {

    view = loadViewFromNib()

    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(view)

}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: CardView.self)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: CardView.self), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
}
```

In my controller, I have the view for index as per the below;

```
func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) -> UIView {

    _ = userResults[Int(index)]

    let bundle = Bundle(for: CardView.self)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: CardView.self), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
```

I am unable to insert my IBOutlets and reference them in my UIViewController.  As I will be getting geoFire & FirDatabase info and populating the views.  I understand this has something to do with the File's Owner.  I'm just unsure on how to set the IBOutlets to the subview instead of the custom class.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why would you let `koloda` method to returns a `UIView` since you are aiming to get a `CardView`?

Comment: First thing I am guessing that CardView is XIB view. And setUp() must not be called explicitly as new CardView will be added on itself(recursion on view initialization). And guessing that you want the label outlets from xib to the view controller itself, you must be changing the file owner to the view controller where you want the outlet.

Comment: @snjmhj That is correct.  I believe the outlets must be added to the CardView class not the ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after hours of tinkering around.

1. Class is now;

   ```
   import UIKit

   class CardView: UIView {

   var uid: String!

   @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

   }
   ```
2. Removed file owner
3. CardView in xib is now set to CardView
4. viewForCardAt is now;

   ```
   func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) -> UIView {

   let bundle = Bundle(for: CardView.self)
   let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: CardView.self), bundle: bundle)
   let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CardView

   let users = userResults[Int(index)]

   view.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: users.userProfileURL))
   view.nameLabel.text = users.userName
   view.uid = users.uid

   return view
   ```

   }

I now have a working "Tinder Card with geoLocating" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting the CardView class to custom class CardView instead of UIView

Comment: If I change loadViewFromNib - let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView to let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CardView and the same in - viewForCardAtIndex I get error (Could not cast value of type 'UIView')